# Python - Objects of a list matching objects positions of another list

Tags: python, maya, autodesk

I'm trying to match positions of objects with similar names from different lists in my maya scene using python.

i.e In my scene there are 100's of big boxes ("Box_01_obj","Box_02_obj"...) and 100's of small boxes ("Box_01_obj_small", "Box_02_obj_small"...) and I'm trying to make those small boxes match big boxes location.

How could I do this using python?

Comment: Please update your post and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
import maya.cmds as mc

for SmallBox in mc.ls("*_small"):
    BigBox = SmallBox.replace("_small","")
    if mc.objExists(BigBox):
        BigBoxPositionX = mc.getAttr(BigBox+".tx")
        mc.setAttr(SmallBox+".tx", BigBoxPositionX)
        
        BigBoxPositionY = mc.getAttr(BigBox+".ty")
        mc.setAttr(SmallBox+".ty", BigBoxPositionY)
        
        BigBoxPositionZ = mc.getAttr(BigBox+".tz")
        mc.setAttr(SmallBox+".tz", BigBoxPositionZ)
```

This will work, assuming that the boxes share the same parent, or are unparented. If not, you'll have to use a more complex align function or parent constrain the small boxes to the big ones and then remove the parent constraint.